# Stompbox / pedal effect that controls pan / blend

Tags: guitar-effects, effects-pedal

I have a dual pickup that outputs to a stereo jack, having the tip and ring outputting the two elements of the pickup respectively.

I was wondering if there is an effect that takes a stereo ¼" jack (or right & left using an insert cable), and has a mono output which is a blend of both channels, with a knob controlling the blend or dry/wet of both stereo sides.

If there is such a pedal, does it have an official name so I can use to search for various makes out there?

It's not a guitar, it's a violin. I don't have the pickup yet, I'm considering buying it, and since it's a bit pricey, I'm checking out the options of the whole gear. [Here](https://ithacastring.com/product/aceto-dual-pickup-mic-system/) is what I'm talking about.

Comment: It's called a blender or mixer pedal

Comment: The site you link suggests a pricey ($1000) blender/preamp that looks like it has a stereo input jack. [Here is a stereo blender pedal](https://xotic.us/effects/stereo-x-blender). But it seems like you could just use a stereo splitter cable and a [regular blender pedal like this](https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/MixBlender--radial-mix-blender-dual-instrument-buffer-mixer-and-fx-loop-interface).

Comment: @Shimmy - I have made these for £5 plus case. It's a really simple circuit. Usually called a mixer pedal.

Comment: @DoktorMayhem, are there blank DIY mini-effect pedals to get anywhere?

Comment: @Shimmy - happy to chat in [chat]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the portion regarding terms of art, try: "stereo summing mono pedal" (or "sum to mono"). Also, possibly crossfade or pan pedal.

I saw someone mention the use of an Ernie Ball 6165, where they put the stereo *input* into the "B" *output*, and then used the "A" *input* ans the mono out, and the pan knob worked to set the mix. This may have been a quirk of an older design, but they claimed it summed properly with no attenuation.

Comment: I also saw DIY electronic books that talk about mods for stereo devices. Schematics only however

Comment: please elaborate about the DIY part, tx

Comment: I saw a google book hit when using google. random hit with schematic: https://www.rane.com/note109.html ( Stereo-to-Mono Summing Box figure 2)

Comment: Why don't you include that in your answer? This IS actually the answer.